# Store Gmail mails in MySQL and email reply is post on my website. is it possible

Tags: php, mysqli, imap, gmail-api, gmail-imap

I am trying to store mail with IMAP and i think this is really complex and slow method. Is there any API from google which can help me store email and reply in MYSQL and post on my website

Comment: Frankly, the API is called IMAP.  You can create a shadow copy in MySQL with fairly small amounts of code by hooking the PHP up to poll the IMAP at interval.  It will be trickier to show the entire threading, but do-able nonetheless.

Comment: If you're using gmail, the gmail (HTTP) API is also available: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/